# Can you automatically insert a namespace in a visual studio snippet?

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

I have a code snippet that creates a C# class for me.  It puts the regions in all the right places and sets it up just the way I like it.

When I create a class by adding a new item it automatically creates the namespace based on my project and folder structure.

Is there a way I could do the same action with my custom snippet?

Is there a way I can change the default class to look like the class format I want?

Comment: Given the new developments it would be appropriate to change the accepted answer for future readers like myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think that this is possible with VS Snippets, there are only a [few available functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312%28VS.80%29.aspx), and they are listed at MSDN. You could, though, create a new Item Template and use the [parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa%28VS.80%29.aspx) $rootnamespace$, which will be replaced with the root namespace of the current project. Item templates are a really useful part of Visual Studio, and MSDN has [extensive documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky%28VS.80%29.aspx) on it and Visual Studio Magazine had a [nice walkthrough](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/columns/article.aspx?editorialsid=2761) about them.

Answer (score 10):

This is possible now (2018), at least part of your's wishes, with adding this:

```
<Snippet>
  ...

  <Imports>
    <Import>
      <Namespace>SomeNamespace</Namespace>
    </Import>
    <Import>
      <Namespace>AnotherNamespace</Namespace>
    </Import>
  </Imports>
</Snippet>
```

For more info: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4457

Comment: Worth noting it is to be included inside your `<Snippet>` node. 
Add an `<Import>` node for each namespace you need.