# Visual Studio 2013: How to add file name to the output of a snippet?

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

I need to include the name of the file that the snippet is being inserted to the output. 
I looked into Code Snippet Functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and the selections are limited.

Is there any way to insert the name of the file that the snippet is being inserted into to the snippet output?

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: @Charles, I am not following. What selecting tags are you referring to?

Comment: The tags on your question, which I see you've edited.  When doing tag edits, an interface appears that displays the descriptions of tags as you type their names.  Please always read those descriptions.  (You used a tag with zero other questions that exists only as a typo, with a description asking you to use the correct tag instead.)

Comment: @Charles: Thank you for the hint. I assume the current tags are relevant to his question.

Answer (score 8):

You can add `${1:${TM_FILENAME_BASE}}` tag in json snippet file to get file name and add it to output of snippet.

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem possible to do with snippets, but it is possible with Item Templates. [See this post for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/826021/1654818)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help: [File Header code snippet](https://gist.github.com/ecampidoglio/1266935) or this one: [Code Snippet Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312.aspx). In short using Declariations->Literals and Code snippet functions should resolve your problem.

Comment: this method only allows for typing the filename manually, not automatically